# AngularJS: Getting multiple values for same variable

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a project using MEAN Stack and still learning the parts of AngularJS.
I have a form which I get filled from the user. It contains a series of checkboxes which selects the students and stores them in an array. For each students, I intend to take 2 values(correct answers, incorrect answers) for that student. How do I model these two inputs to two variables and get the values in the controller?

The problem is that if one time, I select 3 students, there will be 3 pairs of correct and incorrect answers. If other time I have different students selected, how do I map the answers to those students?

View.html:

```
<label ng-repeat="studentA1 in studentsA1">
                <input 
                 type="checkbox"
                 ng-model="selectedStudentsA1"
                 ng-checked="existA1(studentA1)"
                 value="studentA1"
                 ng-click="toggleSelectionA1(studentA1)">
                 {{studentA1}}
</label>
{{selectedStudentsA1}}

<div class="col-md-3">
    <h6>Correct Answers</h6>
    <input type="number" min="0" name="correctAnswers" ng-model="correctAnswers" required>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h6>Incorrect Answers</h6>
    <input type="number" name="incorrectAnswers" ng-model="incorrectAnswers" min="0" required>
</div>
```

Controller.js:

```
    $scope.studentsA1 = ['Akhilesh', 'Prathamesh', 'Mandar', 'Sunmay'];

    $scope.selectedStudentsA1 = [];

    $scope.existA1 = function(item) {
        return $scope.selectedStudentsA1.indexOf(item) > -1;
    };

    $scope.toggleSelectionA1 = function(item) {
        var idx = $scope.selectedStudentsA1.indexOf(item);
        if (idx > -1) {
            $scope.selectedStudentsA1.splice(idx, 1);
        } else {
            $scope.selectedStudentsA1.push(item);
        }
    };

    $scope.checkAllA1 = function() {
        if ($scope.selectAllA1) {
            angular.forEach($scope.studentsA1, function(item) {
                var idx = $scope.selectedStudentsA1.indexOf(item);
                if(idx >= 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $scope.selectedStudentsA1.push(item);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $scope.selectedStudentsA1 = [];
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this helps you 
I have made a fiddle for you
If you are looking more please comment them

In View Side

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="mainController">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="selectAllCheckBox(selectAll)">
      </th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Correct</th>
      <th>Wrong</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="studentA1 in studentsA1">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="studentA1.selected">
      </td>
      <td> {{studentA1.Name}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" ng-model="studentA1.Correct" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" ng-model="studentA1.Wrong" />
      </td>\
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br> {{selectedStudentsA1}}
  <a ng-click="selectedStudents()">Submit</a>
</div>
```

In Controller Side

```
function mainController($scope) {
  $scope.studentsA1 = [{
    selected: false,
    Name: 'Akhilesh',
    Correct: '',
    Wrong: ''
  }, {
    selected: false,
    Name: 'Prathamesh',
    Correct: '',
    Wrong: ''
  }, {
    selected: false,
    Name: 'Mandar',
    Correct: '',
    Wrong: ''
  }, {
    selected: false,
    Name: 'Sunmay',
    Correct: '',
    Wrong: ''
  }];

  $scope.selectedStudents = function() {
    $scope.selectedStudentsA1 = $scope.studentsA1.filter(i => i.selected == true);
    $scope.correctAnswers = $scope.selectedStudentsA1.length;
    $scope.incorrectAnswers = $scope.studentsA1.length -                 $scope.selectedStudentsA1.length;
  }
  $scope.selectAllCheckBox = function(value) {
    $scope.studentsA1.forEach(function(item) {
      item.selected = value;
    });
  }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/9r8sbwx4/

Comment: Yes. I guess that's something I want. However, could you please tell me how to do it with simple array rather than object and output the values to the console? Thanks.

Comment: I think you want the correct answer as an array of names isn't it. for that take the $scope.selectedStudentsA1, it will have the correct answer array with names only

Comment: I intend to get the correct and incorrect answers with the name of corresponding student so that I can then send the to the database. Where I am stuck is that, if I select `Akhilesh`and `Mandar` with say values `(Akhilesh,3, 2)` and `(Mandar, 1, 3)` (just an example). How to get the data in that form. Hope I am not being too ambiguous.

Comment: what those (Akhilesh,3, 2) 3 & 2 suppose to mean and also do you want to send those correct and incorrect values as arrays as here correct = [a,b] & 
incorrect = [c,d]

Comment: It means Akhilesh has 3 correct and 2 incorrect answers. In that structured way. In a more generalized manner, maybe an object like this: `var data = { name: "Akhilesh", correct: 3, incorrect: 2}`. And possibly sending an array of such objects.

Comment: Okay for that it will be good to arrange them in a grid with ng-repeat then take those results with selected true to an array then push those to database.
Please check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/9r8sbwx4/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps. If you could please copy the second fiddle here to your answer, I'll be able to mark it accepted.

Comment: Sure :) Happy to know it worked. If any thing more just ping me.